# Beginners Example: Cypher not returning a node name for one node, but is for all the others

Tags: database, cypher

I'm trying to learn about Cypher using the really basic, beginners example at http://www.neo4j.org/console.

The first query, I attempted is:

```
MATCH (n) 
RETURN n
```

which essentially says:

> "Match all nodes and return them"

The result I get is this:

```
{name:"Neo"}
(1:Crew {name:"Morpheus"})
(2:Crew {name:"Trinity"})
(3:Crew:Matrix {name:"Cypher"})
(4:Matrix {name:"Agent Smith"})
(5:Matrix {name:"The Architect"})
```

This answer seems correct, as these are indeed all the nodes in the database. However, **why does the result for "Neo" not include a number and the type "Crew" like all the others?**
I would expect it to say `(0:Crew {name:"Neo"})`

Answer (score 1):

In fact it should ...

I have checked ajax call, and I have found the label for this node, but  neo4j console doesn't print it. I don't know why for now.

I think this is a bug of the application. 
Can you report it here https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole ?

Cheers.